# scroll event on popup Microsoft Edge Browser not working

Tags: jquery, microsoft-edge

Jquery bind mousewheel event to scroll popup doesn't work with Microsoft Edge.

```
jQuery("#wrapper").unbind('mousewheel').mousewheel(
function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY){
            console.log('mousewheel'+event);
                mainObj.checkout.scrollPopupWindow(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY, targetJqueryObject);
            }
        );

    scrollPopupWindow:function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY, targetJqueryObject){
            console.log('scrollPopupWindow' +jQuery(window).scrollTop() );
        //if(mainObj.checkout.getScroll()){
            jQuery(document).mousedown();
            //if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() == 0 || jQuery(window).scrollTop() == 208){
                var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
                var chkHeight = targetJqueryObject.height() + 60;
                var marginTop = 50;
                var marginBottom = 50;                              
                if(winHeight < (chkHeight + marginTop + 10)){           

                    if(deltaY == null || deltaY == undefined){
                        deltaY = 0;
                    }                                   
                    var multiple = 30;                                  
                    if(navigator.oscpu && navigator.oscpu.indexOf('Windows') != -1){
                        multiple = 30;
                    }else if(navigator.platform && navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') != -1){
                        multiple = 50;
                    }

                    var newTop = targetJqueryObject.offset().top + (deltaY * multiple);
                    var oldTop = targetJqueryObject.offset().top;

                    if(newTop > marginTop){
                        newTop = marginTop;
                    }
                    console.log('scrollPopupWindow newTop' +newTop);            
                    var chkVisible = chkHeight + newTop + marginBottom;                             
                    if(chkVisible <= winHeight){
                        newTop = -1 * (chkHeight - winHeight) - marginBottom;
                    }
```

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: No Error message only . same code work in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: what device are you using? There is a long standing bug with devices that have a precision touch pad lacking the ability to trigger wheel events

Comment: Microsoft surface with Edge browser.